# "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" when using docker_service module with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3"
services:

  container0:
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "10000:22"

  container1:
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "10001:22"

  container2:
    image: myimage
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "10002:22"
```

and the following task in my playbook :

```
    - name: setting up containers
      docker_service:
        project_src: .
        files:
          - docker-compose.yml
        state: present
```

The `docker-compose.yml` seems correct and there is no error when consuming it directly with `docker-compose up`.

But when running my playbook, I get the following :

```
$ ansible-playbook -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3' playbook.yml

PLAY [set up containers] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

[...]

TASK [setting up containers] ***********************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Creating containers_container0_1 ... \r\nCreating containers_container2_1 ... \r\nCreating containers_container1_1 ... \r\n\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\rCreating containers_container0_1 ... \u001b[32mdone\u001b[0m\r\u001b[1B\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\rCreating containers_container2_1 ... \u001b[32mdone\u001b[0m\r\u001b[1B\u001b[1A\u001b[2K\rCreating containers_container1_1 ... \u001b[32mdone\u001b[0m\r\u001b[1BTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hvp0_qgr/ansible_module_docker_service.py\", line 1016, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hvp0_qgr/ansible_module_docker_service.py\", line 1011, in main\n    result = ContainerManager(client).exec_module()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hvp0_qgr/ansible_module_docker_service.py\", line 608, in exec_module\n    result = self.cmd_up()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hvp0_qgr/ansible_module_docker_service.py\", line 703, in cmd_up\n    get_stdout(fd_name)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_hvp0_qgr/ansible_module_docker_service.py\", line 512, in get_stdout\n    new_line = re.sub(r'\\x1b\\[.+m', '', line.encode('ascii'))\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py\", line 191, in sub\n    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)\nTypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/vmonteco/Code/Perso/Ansible/containers/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

What could cause this error?

The containers are still succesfully created and launched after running this command though.

Comment: From the error it seems like a ansible module issue and not related to docker. Please open a issue with ansible team

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you for the advice. I will proceed as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Error excerpt:

> ... File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py\", line 191 ...

Python 3? Ansible is not yet fully compatible with Python 3 (as of time of writing this answer).